# Html, Css, javascript

Tags: html, css

boa noite pessoal, então, gostaria de que ao clicar em uma div(que no caso é um icone), uma outra div se expandise, só que do lado dessa div a outra, eu queria que essa segunda div no caso fica-se atrás da que vier a expandir.
Obrigado

Comment: Cara, sem querer ser chato mas está bem confusa sua pergunta. Tem o começo de algum código, ou exemplo para que podemos ajudar melhor com o que você precisa?

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta ficou meio confusa, mas acho q sei qual a sua dúvida principal, vamos lá:

```
<div id="divDoIcone" onclick="alternaEstadoDiv('idDaDivExpandivel')"  style="display: inline-block; background-color:black; height: 200px; width: 200px">  </div>
<div id="idDaDivExpandivel" style="display: none; background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 200px;" >  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function alternaEstadoDiv(id){
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        if( div.style.display == 'none'){
            div.style.display = "inline-block" // se quiser ter mais de um elemento ou div na mesma linha, se não troque inline-block por block
        }else{
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>


<div style="background-color:yellow; height: 200px; width: 200px"> outro div qualquer </div>
```

Ao clicar no **Div** de id="divDoIcone" a função `alternaEstado( id )` vai procurar pelo div com o id passado e alternar o estado dele para inline-block ( aparecendo) ou para none( não aparecendo ).

Agora dependendo do como vc quer que os div se posicionem, vai ter que alterar algumas propriedades do css ( para isso pode dar uma olhada [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) ).

Snippet mostrando o código acima funcionando:

ps: a organização do código está um pouco diferente no snippet, porém suas propiedades / funcionamento são iguais.

```css
div{
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px
 }
#divDoIcone {
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color:black; 
}
 
#divExpandivel {
  background-color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="divDoIcone" onclick="alternaEstadoDiv('divExpandivel')" > <p style="position: absolute; color: white"> Div clicável </p> </div>
<div id="divExpandivel" style="display: none;" > <p style="position: absolute"> Div expansível </p>  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function alternaEstadoDiv(id){
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        if( div.style.display == 'none'){
            div.style.display = "inline-block" // se quiser ter mais de um elemento ou div na mesma linha, se não troque inline-block por block
        }else{
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>


<div style="background-color:yellow; "> outro div qualquer </div>
```

Comment: pq não coloca um exemplo funcional na resposta pra gente testar a sua resposta. Acho que ficaria melhor e vc poderia ganhar votos e comprovar a sua resposta.

Comment: @dvd feito. agora os div's são quadrados e de cores diferentes. Apenas para melhor compreendimento de quem é quem.

Comment: Cria um snippet pra gente ver funcionando.

Comment: @dvd adicionado o snippet.